# Pandas: how to reorder dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Example:

```
data={'P1_1': ['1', '6', '5','8', '4', '7', '5', '7', '1', '7', '3', '2', '1', '4', '7', '5', '7', '1'],
        'P1_2':['3', '7', '7','9', '8', '10', '8', '9', '3', '10', '9', '5', '3', '8', '9', '6', '7', '5'],
       'P2_1': ['1', '2', '3','4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10', '11', '12', '13', '14', '15', '16', '17', '18'],
         'P2_2': ['3', '7', '7','9', '8', '10', '8', '9', '8', '10', '12', '13', '14', '8', '17', '8', '2', '5']}
df=pd.DataFrame(data)
```

This is the df that I have.

[image]

What I want is now to reorder the columns.
P1 and P2 are the names of a Category, the second number _1 and _2 are time points. Now I want the categories shown in rows and the time points in columns by receiving the values.
It should look the following way:

[image]

In the 2nd example I added a 3rd P only for having more values.

I think there might be a familiar way. Can anyone give me a direction to think?

Comment: What is logic for `P3` ? It not exist in sample input data?

Comment: In the 2nd example I added a 3rd P only for having more values. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
data={'Punkte_Teil1_1': ['1', '6', '5','8', '4', '7', '5', '7', '1', '7', '3', '2', '1', '4', '7', '5', '7', '1'],
      'Punkte_Teil1_2': ['3', '7', '7','9', '8', '10', '8', '9', '3', '10', '9', '5', '3', '8', '9', '6', '7', '5'],
      'Punkte_Teil2_1': ['1', '2', '3','4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10', '11', '12', '13', '14', '15', '16', '17', '18'],
      'Punkte_Teil2_2': ['3', '7', '7','9', '8', '10', '8', '9', '8', '10', '12', '13', '14', '8', '17', '8', '2', '5']}
df=pd.DataFrame(data)

print (df)
   Punkte_Teil1_1 Punkte_Teil1_2 Punkte_Teil2_1 Punkte_Teil2_2
0               1              3              1              3
1               6              7              2              7
2               5              7              3              7
3               8              9              4              9
4               4              8              5              8
5               7             10              6             10
6               5              8              7              8
7               7              9              8              9
8               1              3              9              8
9               7             10             10             10
10              3              9             11             12
11              2              5             12             13
12              1              3             13             14
13              4              8             14              8
14              7              9             15             17
15              5              6             16              8
16              7              7             17              2
17              1              5             18              5
```

Use [`DataFrame.pipe`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pipe.html) for set MultiIndex by last _ by [`str.rsplit`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.rsplit.html), then set new column name by [`DataFrame.rename_axis`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rename_axis.html), reshape by [`DataFrame.stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html), use [`DataFrame.add_prefix`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.add_prefix.html) and last convert second level of MultiIndex to column by [`DataFrame.reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html), second is for create default `RangeIndex`:

```
df = (df.pipe(lambda x: x.set_axis(x.columns.str.rsplit('_', expand=True, n=1), axis=1))
        .rename_axis(['Cat',None], axis=1)
        .stack(0)
        .add_prefix('T')
        .reset_index(level=1)
        .reset_index(drop=True))
print (df.head())
            Cat T1 T2
0  Punkte_Teil1  1  3
1  Punkte_Teil2  1  3
2  Punkte_Teil1  6  7
3  Punkte_Teil2  2  7
4  Punkte_Teil1  5  7
```

Comment: Thx for kicking me ;-) And sorry, the examples that I used are noct exactly from the same df. But you understand what I mean.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't really understand all the details, so I can't transfer the solution to my real df, which consists of more than 2 columns. Which part of the code is the one, that refers to the number of columns and I also have to modify. In my df there are 10 columns.

Comment: @Kajette - What is `print (df.columns.tolist())` ?

Comment: ['Punkte_Teil1_1', 'Punkte_Teil1_2', 'Punkte_Teil2_1', 'Punkte_Teil2_2', 'Punkte_Teil3_1', 'Punkte_Teil3_2', 'Punkte_Teil4_1', 'Punkte_Teil4_2', 'Punkte_Teil5_1', 'Punkte_Teil5_2']

Comment: @Kajette - thank you, answer was edited by `rsplit` and `n=1` in first line of code.

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea what your data meant and why or how you want it to become that way, but I can share with you some techniques using `pandas`.

I hope that this can perhaps kick you off in direction you need.

```py
import pandas as pd

data = ...

def concat_args(*args):
    return ";".join(*args)

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df = df.melt()
df["category"] = df["variable"].apply(lambda x: x.split("_")[0])
df["timepoint"] = df["variable"].apply(lambda x: f"T{x.split('_')[1]}")
df = pd.pivot_table(
    df, index="category", columns="timepoint", values="value", aggfunc=concat_args
)
print(df)
```

Expected results:

```py
timepoint                                            T1                                         T2
category                                                                                          
P1                  1;6;5;8;4;7;5;7;1;7;3;2;1;4;7;5;7;1      3;7;7;9;8;10;8;9;3;10;9;5;3;8;9;6;7;5
P2         1;2;3;4;5;6;7;8;9;10;11;12;13;14;15;16;17;18  3;7;7;9;8;10;8;9;8;10;12;13;14;8;17;8;2;5
```